# Error bar visibility

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel template to produce multiple charts - over 20 charts arranged on different sheets.

I would like to assign a macro to a button or two buttons to add/ remove error these bars basically by manipulating the transparancy of the line ...

I was helped out with the following code that does work when each sheet is clicked on:

```
Sub Macro2()

Dim objCht As ChartObject
Dim ws As Worksheet

' loop through sheets in this workbook
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
' loop through Chartobjects in sheet
For Each objCht In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
    ' no need to select the chart or the series use With statement instead
    With objCht.Chart.SeriesCollection(1)
       .HasErrorBars = True
        With .ErrorBars.Format.Line
            .Visible = msoTrue
            .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorText1
            .ForeColor.TintAndShade = -0.0500000119
            .ForeColor.Brightness = 0
            .Transparency = 1
        End With
      End With
   Next objCht
Next ws

End Sub
```

The following is saved on each worksheet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
Macro2
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing line `For Each objCht In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects` to `For Each objCht In ws.ChartObjects`. You loop multiple times through sheets without using them. In second approach, every loop you change sheet.

Comment: Any ideas how to re-add the error bars? If I use the same code with Transparency=0